# How to change column name of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web-applications

```
con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database.mdb");
com = new OleDbCommand("Select * from testing", con);
con.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader;
reader = com.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataMember = "testing";
GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
reader.Close();
con.Close();
```

This is the code to view all data into GridView, but the column name is follow database, how can I change the column name?

Comment: Read this article [How-to-bind-GridView-with-DataReader-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-GridView-with-DataReader-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) and I assume you want to change `HeaderText` property of `GridView` which is also demonstrated there (ContactName as Contac**t N**ame)

Answer (score 0):

```
testdgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Date";
```

or

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Name";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "City";
        }
    }
```